# Can't Get Docker Containers to Link on Localhost on MacOS

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've spent a lot of time trying to get NGINX + Sinatra to talk to each other on localhost on my mac. The docker container for Sinatra defined with a dockerfile can load on localhost:3000 without a problem. The NGINX container (with a custom default.conf file) cannot communicate upstream to my app. The docker-compose file is below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  sinatra:
    build: app/
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"

  nginx: 
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: production_nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/default.conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - sinatra
    links:
      - sinatra
```

In default.conf for nginx I have the following:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://sinatra:3000;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }    
}
```

My understanding is the 'link' directive will let me refer to the sinatra service this way. However, it is not working. My share path with my local mac configured in Docker will allow files from all these sources and I can see them when I exec into the individual containers. Any ideas why this won't work? Again, the sinatra service is responding on localhost:3000, so it must be something with the NGINX piece. Thank you for any direction.

Comment: In what way isn't it working?  `links:` is unnecessary these days (the names of services in the `docker-compose.yml` are valid host names); does removing it help?  Also note that "localhost" has a specific technical meaning, especially around Docker (your host, the Sinatra container, and the Nginx container each believe `localhost` is something different) so be careful how you use that term.

Comment: Thanks  @DavidMaze what I mean is that I expect localhost:80 to upstream to the sinatra application, but it isn't doing that. it just registers the 'welcome to nginx page'. where i'm confused is that when i access localhost:3000 the sinatra app will display. it feels like the nginx container can't speak to sinatra. Also I did remove the links directive and changed localhost in the nginx config to 'default_server'. will update the question.

Comment: That sounds like it's not finding the config file.  [The image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) suggests to me that you should mount the config file to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` in the image (not `default.conf`).

Comment: Ugh. Thank you @DavidMaze. Despite configuring NGINX many times I definitely flubbed here. That was the issue.